# extra css is not loaded. any suggestions?

Tags: css, wordpress

I've added the following to my `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px)" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/tablet.css" />`
```

For the main page which is header.php, it is working fine. But if I go to lets say: http://mysyte.com/products-page/checkout/ after inspecting with firebug I can see that the browser didnt even loaded this file even if I assigned a lot of properties for the page in this file (tablet.css).

What can you suggest, where to look for the problem? Thanks!

P.S. platform - wordpress and ecommerce wp plugin.

Comment: Compare the generated HTML sources, and you will find the cause of the error within seconds.

Comment: And if not, tell us the difference ...

Comment: what do you mean by didn't load the file- everything breaks because the CSS isn't rendered? or is it not re-downloaded? probably cached if it's the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried echoing the bloginfo function such as...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px)" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/tablet.css" />`
```